# Parse the output field of getrawtransaction to generate a common address hash

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, address, public-key, bitcoin-cli

Consider the following coinbase transaction:

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d70ae1131d433b655d0faeae1db4efa15bb4138f1e38e60a53073a58ea1dcc34

How we can retrieve the recipient address, i.e. `1JAL1WRvwbJqWWd1Ktks4Q89zCeUYSQM12` using the output field of the RPC command below:

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction d70ae1131d433b655d0faeae1db4efa15bb4138f1e38e60a53073a58ea1dcc34 1


"vout": [
    {
      "value": 50.12000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0400d0ade32217e076945e0946ef7bed72d9aea035aa8891e4bf0749ae6e24f8a7d3ea56efafe472ac3943dbed3af7c093729720ac9ab04e8eba09286e3a00fe41 OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "410400d0ade32217e076945e0946ef7bed72d9aea035aa8891e4bf0749ae6e24f8a7d3ea56efafe472ac3943dbed3af7c093729720ac9ab04e8eba09286e3a00fe41ac",
        "type": "pubkey"
      }
    }
  ],
```

For non-coinbase transactions, the output filed contains the value of addresses.

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction bd20f46a4337ab787f6fbd036e9f4d65c7ae67d21cc6f9013162e783384d877c 1

"vout": [
    {
      "value": 1.00000000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 53c32617316707bb8ba4e1546fa8c32bd212c86d OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a91453c32617316707bb8ba4e1546fa8c32bd212c86d88ac",
        "address": "18dts6fXXA7jVKfYMBpsFqx7iZCELCfDpk",
        "type": "pubkeyhash"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 58.97000000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 37fdd890381f9965d620fc3d0c9fa3e511cb1449 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a91437fdd890381f9965d620fc3d0c9fa3e511cb144988ac",
        "address": "1674G5SSZAb7h4unJMjdxfgNwo71vxgGQg",
        "type": "pubkeyhash"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the type of the output is:

> "type": "pubkey"

Pay-to-Public-Key (P2PK) outputs do not have addresses. They pay directly to a public key rather than the hash of the public key, as the name suggests. Bitcoin addresses encode public key hashes, for example, addresses starting with a `1` are known as Pay-to-Public-Key-Hash (P2PKH) addresses and encode the `Ripemd-160(sha-256(public key))`.

See my other answer [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/111429/51948) for the same sort of question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll follow the steps provided in the wiki to see how services like blockchain.com or blockchair.com pull out such addresses.